# Eclipse fonts are unreadable in ubuntu fix

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

Now i am coding in ubuntu, installed ADT and started coding. But the problem is that some fonts in eclipse are not readable because, their color is same as the background color of eclipse, which is black. when i select them as a whole, i can see every thing, what is wrong here? Please help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **ONE** of these:

1. Change the theme. Go to Windows > Preferences. Then go to General > Appearance . Refer pic below. Restart eclipse after changing the theme to take effect.
   [image]
2. Install [Eclipse colour](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) theme plugin so that you will get lots of option to switch theme.
   Restart eclipse after changing the theme to take effect.
3. Also you can override GTK settings. Refer this [link](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/12/04/eclipse-papercut-10-eclipse-on-ubuntu-fixing-the-black-background-color-in-hover/)